# Use Roboto monospaced font for \url

Tags: fonts, hyperref, typewriter

I am using the [Roboto](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/roboto) font for section titles; I also want to use it for `ttfamily` kind of cases, such as `\url`, especially because it is more condensed than the default font. Looking at the [font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/roboto/), there is a monospaced version. But how do I "enable" it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[lf]{venturis}
\usepackage[condensed]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Foo: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}

\end{document}
```

Whether or whether not I include the `roboto` package, the URL is always rendered the same in a relatively wide monospaced font which AFAICS is not Roboto:

[image]
[image]

I think I need something like

```
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{roboto}
```

Only, the font name is invalid. I guess it's abbreviated, but how?

Answer (score 2):

It's in the package read-me: there is a second package `roboto-mono`. E.g.

```
\usepackage[light,scaled=0.85]{roboto-mono}
```

It doesn't buy much horizontal space, though.
[image]

Comment: I just did a quick search, and it appears there is no roboto condensed mono font, just regular width. My test run gives \`Font shape \`T1/RobotoMono-TLF/l/n' undefined'. Is this just my situation, or is it true for all? Would `\urlstyle{rm}` be suitable?

Comment: I should say `\urlstyle{sf}` for vari-width Roberto.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau yes, here too, only regular width, so I can only scale it down completely.